# "Getting started with a secure static website" Tutorial Fails with cannot create S3BucketLogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use the [Getting started with a secure static website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started-secure-static-website-cloudformation-template.html) AWS tutorial so that I can have HTTPS on my websites I host from a S3 bucket. However, I on the CustomResourceStack step I get the error:

`Embedded stack ... was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [S3BucketLogs].`

I have Block all public access set to "Off".

My Object Ownership is "Bucket owner preferred"

My Access control list (ACL)
Bucket owner (your AWS account): Objects (List,Write), Bucket ACL (Read,Write)

My Bucket policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1683687093748",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example.com/*"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: There's an open issue for this on GitHub - it's not you!
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-secure-static-site/issues/60

Comment: Oh thank you! I was banging my head against the wall. The issue is closed now. I tried again and it worked!